# Boolean search fuzzy query for Elasticsearch - Unexpected result - "Word1" AND "Word2" ~3

Tags: elasticsearch, search, boolean, logic, fuzzy

I was using the search string '"Word1" AND "Word2" ~3' in an Elasticsearch app, but was getting a result that I didn't expect.

It was returning results such as "Word1 blah blah Word1".  I actually only wanted it to return results for "Word1 blah blah Word2", but not duplicate occurrences of "Word1".

In experimenting it seems '"Word1 Word2" ~3' gives the actual result I was looking for.

Is someone able to help me to understand this logic, and why the first search does not work as expected, and if there is a better approach to what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first query `"Word1" AND "Word2" ~3`, the fuzziness is only applied on `Word2`. The query reads basically like this: Find all documents containing "Word1" and "Word2" with an edit distance of 3. So the document with `Word1 blah blah Word1` would qualify since the first occurrence of "Word1" matches and the second occurrence also because it has an edit distance of 1 with "Word 2"

In your second query `"Word1 Word2" ~3`, you're doing a [proximity search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_proximity_searches), i.e. it is a phrase query in which you allow "Word1" and "Word2" to be further apart from one another.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that explains it.  I feel like something you've said is contradictory though.  Can you check/explain?
"the fuzziness is only applied on Word2" - this doesn't seem to be the case, because of what you said later about "Word1 blah blah Word1".  "~3" seems to apply to both "Word1" and "Word2".
However you've very much helped me with your explanation and that makes a lot of sense and explains what I was seeing.  Many thanks.  Just thought it might warrant a minor edit if there is opportunity to clean-up the explanation, because it's very useful.  Thanks

Comment: No, in the first query you have `AND` which means that the fuzziness only applies to `Word2`. In your second query both words and within double quotes, which means that it is a phrase and thus the fuzziness applies to the phrase.